# Grails Missing type or column for column[order_items_order_item] on domain[rewards.OnlineOrder] referencing[rewards.OrderItem]

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

So I keep getting the subject line error when trying to run my grails app. Here are my two domain classes that appear to be the cause of the error.

OnlineOrder:

```
package rewards

class OnlineOrder {

    Date orderDate
    Integer orderNumber
    Float orderTotal

    static belongsTo = [customer:Customer]
    static hasMany = [orderItems:OrderItem]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

OrderItem:

```
package rewards

class OrderItem {

    Integer qty
    Float total

    static belongsTo = [orders:OnlineOrder, product:Product]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Error reads as: `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Missing type or column for column[order_items_order_item] on domain[rewards.OnlineOrder] referencing[rewards.OrderItem]`

It looks like it's saying that I haven't defined OrderItem yet and I'm referencing it as a child in my OnlineOrder domain. But I can't seem to figure out why that is causing an error. OrderItem class is created in the same directory as OnlineOrder and is fairly straightforward.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this in a way that can be generalized? I am running into nearly the same issue using Grails 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but it hadn't any sense.

My solution was run

```
grails clean
```

and then run the project again

```
grails -reloading run-app
```

If your project uses migrations, is recommended that you put the database on a stable state an then run the following commands:

```
grails clean
grails dbm-clear-checksums
grails dbm-update
grails -reloading run-app
```

Answer (score 1):

i had similar problem in application the same was resolved by deteting the class file from target folder and re run the application . this error ususlly comes because i had changed a property name in my domin and had created new db colum in database .

regards,
Raouf

Comment: I don't know why, but that happen to me, it does not make any sense. Sometimes I feel it's just buggy.

Answer (score 0):

We were facing a similar issue when running the Starter Class directly from the IDE. After a change to a domain class IntelliJ did a make but did not put all the Grails / Gorm Annotations into the bytecode. Then GrailsAutoConfiguration does not load the Artefact in scanUsingPattern.

Use javap to see the bytecode of your domains.

For us running grails run-app seems far better.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I had this same problem in my grails app when I added a collection to an object.

What happened was I used IntelliJ to auto-create the groovy class from the little suggest fix options. I didn't realize it but it created the new class under init as opposed to domain.  After I moved it to the domain classes, everything was happy.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
package rewards

class OrderItem {

    Integer qty
    Float total
    OnlineOrder onlineOrder
    Product product

    static belongsTo = [OnlineOrder, Product]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

And please use BigDecimal instead of Float.